# Can I ask about Mozilla's "XPCOM deprecation" on SO?

Tags: discussion, scope

Part of my programming is linked to the Mozilla XPCOM (cross platform COM) toolset, present in Firefox and Thunderbird.

I would like to ask a question about this tool (which is used to create/program software). I think it would fit on Stack Overflow as it would be a question:

> software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
>   as laid out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

My question would regard my challenge understanding how XPCOM is deprecated by Mozilla. Specifically I would like to ask other users/or Mozilla people browsing Stack Overflow if XPCOM will be removed from Firefox and other Mozilla products entirely or simply from the extensions APIs, as a way to coerce to `WebExtensions` as suggested at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM

Comment: You'd be better off asking on the mozilla mailing list perhaps this one: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mozilla.dev.platform

Comment: Since only an authoritative person at Mozilla can answer that with any certainty, I doubt it's appropriate for SO. Questions about implementing a workaround would probably do fine

Comment: You would need to be significantly more specific than you were in this question (e.g. don't conflate Firefox and Thunderbird). You should avoid asking what will happen in the future, other than asking about what has been announced will happen. Stay away from things which imply interpreting intent (e.g. "as a way to coerce to WebExtensions"). Basically, ask about facts, not opinions. Also, do some searching, as almost all answers will be based on what Mozilla has announced, which can be found with simple Google searches.

Comment: The plan is to remove XPCOM entirely. It will be deprecated from extensions so that they remove it without breaking extensions. The same is true for XUL. WebExtensions were created because they planned on removing XUL and XPCOM, not the other way around.

Comment: *“without breaking extensions”* – Although by deprecating it, they are effectively breaking most of the extensions anyway. There has been a bit outcry from extension developers about it, but it seems that Mozilla is keeping the plan as it is, even though WebExtensions is not (yet?) able to offer the capabilities so many extensions build upon.

Answer (score 28):

I personally don't see anything wrong with asking this type of question. Certainly it fits within the *technical* scope, as you mentioned.

However, as the two comments to the question suggest, it's a constant debate here on Meta whether a question becomes off-topic simply because there are an extremely small number of people who will be able to answer it. Clive notes that "only an authoritative person at Mozilla can answer that with any certainty [so] I doubt it's appropriate for SO." The same logic has been used to reject questions about the design of specific languages—the thinking goes, essentially, that only the people who designed the language would be able to answer it, so it's off-topic.

I am suspect of this entire chain of reasoning. There are lots of questions that get asked every day on Stack Overflow that only a vanishingly small number of people in the world actually know the answer to. Questions on highly specialized technologies, obsolete technologies, extremely complex/technical questions, and so on are all acceptable, regardless of the size of their target audience. It may be that many of these questions never do get an answer, and that certainly is unfortunate, but it doesn't make the question inherently off-topic. A crystal ball should not be required to determine topicality. It just means you might not get an answer, and you have to consider whether it's really worth spending the time to ask and waiting around for an answer that may never come. You may be better off investing the time in implementing a workaround, pursuing an alternative, or committing to a redesign.

That said, some of these highly-specialized questions *do* get an answer. I've trotted this example out before, but it remains compelling. Questions that have been previously dismissed as off-topic because only someone involved in the design of the C# language would be able to answer them have actually been answered by one of our members who *was* involved in (some) aspects of the design of the C# language! Granted, you can't *expect* this to happen in all cases, but this is one of the virtues of Stack Overflow—a place where experts gather to share their knowledge. If you could only ask questions where you could guarantee that lots of people knew the answer, this would be just another "debug my code for me" web forum, and I certainly don't want that.

So, if it were me, I'd go ahead and ask it. But be prepared for some blow-back, and possibly some close votes. Maybe even a closure war. Shrug. There's nothing we could say on Meta anyway that would prevent this from happening. Even if we were to reach an impossible consensus on the topicality of the question, that wouldn't stop others from disagreeing and voting to close it anyway. The best we can really do is help you to formulate the question in an acceptable manner. Along those lines, the best recommendation I can give you is to keep the question *narrowly focused* and *contextualized*—in the context of a specific project or problem that you're having. Resist the temptation to make it broad in hopes that it will be useful/applicable to more people. It won't; it'll just make it seem unfocused and thus persistent itchiness on close-vote trigger fingers.

Anyway, it sounds to me like XPCOM is being removed entirely from the Gecko project. But the true answer to your question might ultimately come down to a quibble over the definition of the word "deprecation", and how deprecation is specifically to be implemented. I suspect that's why there is a tendency to conclude that this question would be off-topic, which is why I recommended that you carefully contextualize it. Then, answers about how you could work around the problem become relevant.

Comment: I share some of your reservations about "_Only a few people could answer --> off-topic_", but I suspect there's a "category difference" (or some-such phrase) involved. A question about an obscure image-processing algorithm that only a couple of experts in the field might be able to answer fully _feels_ different to a question about third-party software that only one of their employees (or similar) can answer authoritatively (especially if there are more forum-style places where the question could be better asked).

Comment: Not really. Virtually everything we deal with here is "third-party software". Sure, some programming languages are open standards, I guess, but plenty of development tools are third-party software, and questions about using/targeting them are not off-topic. If you can't answer authoritatively, then you can't answer the question. The fact that we don't currently have anyone who can answer authoritatively doesn't make the question off-topic, and it certainly isn't a justification to drive the asker to the slums.

Comment: There's still a difference in questions that *anyone* could answer authoritatively, if they have access to the systems in question and sufficient time (and the proof of this authority is in the verifiable answer) and questions that *only very particular people* can answer authoritatively because they are the only ones privy to knowledge that was never recorded anywhere. I'm not saying that difference is what (should) determine topicality, but it does explain the resentment of questions that you can't answer but speculatively, even if you had all the time and money in the world.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how this question is something only the developers would know. I can tell you right now what the plan is (and I did so in a comment). The plan to remove XPCOM from Firefox has been publicized for a while now.

I do agree that asking the mailing lists is a better choice, though.

Comment: Where has it been publicized? and if so how comes that on the cited page from mozilla's MDN about specifically XPCOM it does not state so? It only states the deprecation for extensions, but not the core products. Can you post info where I find the info?

Answer (score 0):

I think that such a question would be borderline.

- Asking how XPCOM deprecation is going to be implemented could be interpreted as asking us to predict the future.  (We are not party to the plans ... and besides, they could change.)  Alternatively, the Mozilla organization could already have published their plans ... in which case, the question should not need to be asked.
- A question asking how XPCOM deprecation is going to happen could easily be written with an implied (or explicit) "... and why".  That would definitely call for an opinion-based answer ... because the real (full) answer to "why" is only known to Mozilla management.

Comment: "could already have published". **Everything** that is on SO has already been published elsewhere in some form or another. be it in a text book, a design spec, official documentation or else. by that stanard, no question would be on-topic except for question that equire genuine research. Thats hardly any question on SO.

Comment: Yes ... but that doesn't **prevent** people from doing their own research!  The real point is that if the definitive information is not available, the Q can't be answered ... without speculation ... aka Opinion-based Answer.